# Crystal 13 parameter paging

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I am looking for a way to turn off the parameter 'paging' dropdown when running a report.

For example, I have a report that returns all jobs numbers.  There are maybe 240 total job numbers.  When I run the report, the list box only contains about 50 jobs and has a drop down under the selection box with values 1-5.

switching from 1 to 2 changes the available jobs to the next 50 or so.

Is there a way to turn this off, so that all available jobs are contained in the list box (without the need to page through them)

Seems to have popped up in Crystal 13  (just upgraded from Crystal 11 and never had this before)

thanks

Comment: Normally when there are more values to show in paramter then paging will be added automatically... I too have faced this issue but not sure how to overcome this but I am interested to understand how this is causing you the problem

Comment: Its just 'extra' steps that the client has to take which usually annoys them. In this case the Job numbers are 9 digit numbers.  Previously, you just click  in the box and start to type in the value and it will go to what you type.

Now, I start to type it in, but no matching result is found, and then I have to switch to page 2 and test again, and then again for page 3, etc.  This can add an extra minute or so when it use to just take 10 seconds.